# Need to create a thread for spinner?

Tags: android, multithreading, progressdialog

My code is here

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progress.setTitle("Loading");
    progress.setMessage("Wait while loading...");
    progress.show();
    Log.i("Spinner", "Starts");
    String trip_id = trips.get(position);
    FeedParser parser = FeedParserFactory.getParser(ParserType.ANDROID_SAX);
    stopTimes = parser.parseStopTime().get(trip_id);
    Collections.sort(stopTimes,StopTime.StopTimeComparator);
    stops = parser.parseStop();
    List<String> stopList = new ArrayList<String>(stopTimes.size());
    for (StopTime st: stopTimes) {
        stopList.add(stops.get(st.getStop_id()).getStop_name() + st.getDeparture_time().toString());
    }
    Log.i("Spinner", "Dismissed");
//      progress.dismiss();
    Intent viewStops = new Intent(this, StopActivity.class);
    viewStops.putStringArrayListExtra("stops_to_parse", (ArrayList<String>) stopList);
    this.startActivity(viewStops);
}
```

When the list is clicked, I want to show a spinner indicating a loading while the program loads some other stuff, then dismiss it and turn to another activity.

But what it does is when you click on the list, it just load stuff, without displaying the spinner, then after all stuff is loaded, the spinner suddenly flashes out and then turn to another view.

Apparently, the program is busying loading other stuff that not able to display the spinner until it finishes.

How to show a spinner while the program is computing other stuff correctly?

Comment: Please clear your concepts for Android. A `Spinner` is a view used to display list of elements. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening is that you are doing time-consuming work(loading data) in the main thread(the UI thread). While you are loading the data, the interface is frozen and unable to draw or interact.

To solve this, you must move your time-consuming task to another thread. To do this you can use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), or plain Java threads if you prefer.

In your main thread:

1. Show the spinner
2. Start the new thread

In your new thread:

1. Do the work
2. Hide the spinner

You can find many AsyncTask tutorials online.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)